# How to create preexisting realm db?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've googled for Realm tutorials but I only find examples of how to implement a DB in apps where the user fills the fields (like Contact Apps, To Do apps, etc); they're great, but they do not explain what I want to do.

I'm building a spanish-mayan dictionary app so I don't need that the user enter any data, I only need to display it. I've chosen Realm because it really caught my attention, but I don't seem to find a solution for what I want. Is it possible to create a Realm Object, set its values, populate its data and then display it on a UITableView?

I'm using Swift 2.1.1 and Xcode 7.2

Comment: Yes of course. It's right there in the docs.

Comment: Where? I've literally wandered around the docs and didn't found anything. Do you mind sharing the link?

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/   There's hardly a word about UI in there at all.

Answer (score 0):

We don't really have any official tools or utilities that can produce pre-made Realm files, but it is something we're actively working on at the moment.

At the moment, the easiest thing (And would ultimately give you the most control) would be to write a small desktop app (Maybe even a command line utility) to import your dictionary data, format it, and then save it out to a Realm file beforehand.

After that, you can simply import the Realm file (and the model classes from the utility app) into your proper app, and you can load the data from there.

Comment: I might try that, although I'm not sure how to do it. I have a database written in SQLite with the data I want to implement, is it possible to convert it into a realm file? I googled it and found something about loading it and then moving the data to Realm.